# React-Native TextInput focus on a FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a component that renders a [`<FlatList />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) and every item on that list is a [`<TextInput />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput).

What I want to achieve is basically jump between those TextInputs when they are submitted, using the Input `ref.focus()` method and [`onSubmitEditing`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting) props. The thing is that since the FlatList is dynamic and every item has his own `key` prop meaning that every component rendered in the list is a different instance, I can't find a way to save all the TextInput references and then use them to jump to the next TextInputs.

Expo Demo: https://snack.expo.io/@karljs/react-native-textinput-flatlist

```
    class Input extends Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.inputRef = null;
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              ref={(ref) => this.inputRef = ref}
            />
            // onSubmitEditing={() => this.nextInput.focus() }}
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
              data={[{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Paul'}]}
              renderItem={({item, index}) => <Input
                key={index}
                name={item.name}
              />}
            />     
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You can see it on the Expo link but I'm appending it to the post https://snack.expo.io/@karljs/react-native-textinput-flatlist

Answer (score 0):

My way...

```
renderItem(data) {
const { item } = data;
return (
<View>
<TextInput
 ref={(input) => { this['input_' + item.iter] = input; }}
 onSubmitEditing={() => { this['input_' + (item.iter + 1)].focus(); }}
 blurOnSubmit={false}
 selectTextOnFocus
 keyboardType={'numeric'}
 defaultValue={0}
 placeholder="0"
 onChangeText={text => this.changeItem(text, item)}
/>
</View >)
}

<FlatList
 data={doc.products}
 renderItem={item => this.renderItem(item)}
 keyExtractor={item => item.iter.toString()}
 extraData={doc.products}
/>
```