# React Native: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. Using expo-checkbox on Android

Tags: react-native, android-checkbox

I am trying to create a simple to do list app. Everything is working in the web, but on android I am getting the error written in the title.

I have no issues when I comment out value and onValueChange inside the CheckBox, but a crash with that code included.

I have looked for some issues mentioned elsewhere, such as whitespace and conditional rendering, but none apply here as far as I can tell.

Here is my code:

```js
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';
import CheckBox from 'expo-checkbox';

const Task = props => {
    let data = props.data;
    //console.log(data.created, data.done, data.text, data.focus);
    const [valueDisplayed, onChangeText] = useState(data.text);
    return (
        <View style={styles.task}>
            <CheckBox
                value={data.done}
                onValueChange={(value)=>{props.finish(data.created)}}
            />
            <TextInput
                value={valueDisplayed}
                onChangeText={input => {
                    onChangeText(input);
                    props.update(data.created, input);
                }}
                style={styles.textBox}
                onKeyPress={keyPress => {
                    console.log(keyPress.nativeEvent.key);
                    if (keyPress.nativeEvent.key == "Enter") {
                        props.add(data.created);
                    } else if (data.text.length == 0 && 
                        keyPress.nativeEvent.key == "Backspace") {
                        props.delete(data.created);
                    }
                }}
                onSubmitEditing={() => {
                    props.add(data.created);
                }}
                autoFocus={data.focus}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    task: {
        flexDirection: "row",
    },
    textBox: {
        flex: 1,
        fontSize: 32,
    }
});

export default Task;
```

Thanks for your help :)

...as requested, here is an extract from the parent component:

```js
const finishItem = async (list, created, setTasks) => {
    let array = await loadList(list);
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i].created == created)
            if (array[i].done == 0)
                array[i].done = Date.now();
            else
                array[i].done = 0;
    sortTasks(array);
    setTasks(array);
    await saveList(list, array);
}

const TaskList = (props) => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        getInitialList(props.list, setTasks);
    }, []);
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={tasks}
            extraData={tasks}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
                <Task
                    data={item}
                    add={(createdFrom) => {
                        addItem(props.list, createdFrom, setTasks);
                    }}
                    update={(created, text) => {
                        updateItem(props.list, created, text, setTasks);
                    }}
                    delete={(created) => {
                        deleteItem(props.list, created, setTasks);
                    }}
                    finish={(created) => {
                        finishItem(props.list, created, setTasks);
                    }}
                />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => {
                return item.created
            }}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        />
    );
}
```

Logging the attributes of data gives:
`1690929274428 0 'f' false`

Comment: Please include the code for `props.finish` and what you see when you log out `data`

Comment: @Abe Appended to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expo-checkbox only expects a boolean in its `value` prop. You should only send it values of `true` or `false`.

On the web, expo runs Javascript, which will coerce the 'f' to `true`, since all non-empty strings are truthy in Javascript. In Java/Kotlin (and Objective-C/Swift - I would expect a similar error on iOS), type mismatches are not as forgiving.

Check the props here - https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/checkbox/#value

Comment: That has fixed it, thanks. I did have a boolean there at one point and for whatever reason changed it.

Comment: If you are up for it, I have another question about another issue in this same project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76815157/react-native-how-do-i-focus-on-a-textinput-which-is-inside-a-flatlist-programma

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped, please accept it as the solution, or if you solved it another way, feel free to add your own answer and accept that.